# Does separability imply the Lindelöf property?

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples

Does separability imply a sort of Lindelöf property?

Since I can't prove this fact I'm beginning to think that my conjecture is false.

Intuitively, $\mathbb{R}$ has a countable subset $\mathbb{Q}$ which is used to form a countable basis for $\mathbb{R}$ with the usual topology and prove the Lindeöf property.

Comment: They are the same in metric spaces, but my intuition is that this result doesn't hold generally

Comment: They are the same in the space with point countable base. Note that every metric space has a point countable base.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Counterexamples in Topology* lists several spaces which are separable but not Lindelöf.  You can generate a list at [Spacebook](http://austinmohr.com/home/?page_id=146).

Comment: This Spacebook is amazing! +1.

Answer (score 1):

A nice example that is useful to know is the [Mrówka space $\Psi$](http://dantopology.wordpress.com/tag/mrowka-space/), which among other things is Tikhonov, separable, pseudocompact, not countably compact, and not Lindelöf. I also described it briefly in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/96388/12042), where I gave an example of a specific open cover with no countable subcover. [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/145786/12042) contains a more complete description of the construction of the space, and [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/278840/12042) has another way to get the almost disjoint sets that are needed.

Answer (score 0):

Every seperable meta-Lindelöf (or meta-compact) space is Lindelöf.

We say a space is meta-Lindelöf (meta-compact)  if every open cover has a point countable(finite) open refinement. That is, given any open cover of the topological space, there is a refinement which is again an open cover with the property that every point is contained only in countably(finitely) many sets of the refining cover.

Proof:
Given a space $X$, and an open cover $\mathfrak U$ of $X$, by the meta-Lindelöf property get a point countable open refinement $\mathfrak V$ of $\mathfrak U$. So, for every $x\in X$ the set $\mathfrak V_x=\{V\in\mathfrak V:x\in V\}$ is countable. If $D$ is a countable dense subset of $X$, observe that $\mathfrak V=\bigcup_{x\in D} \mathfrak V_x$, so $\mathfrak V$ is countable. Now, since $\mathfrak V$ is an open refinement of $\mathfrak U$, for each $V_n\in \mathfrak V$ exists $U_n\in\mathfrak U$ for each $n\in\mathbb N$, so the cover $\mathfrak W=\{U_n:n\in\mathbb N\}$ is a countable subcover of $\mathfrak U$. So $X$ is Lindelöf.