# How to compute the measure induced by a linear functional

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

The Riesz representation theorem states that for any linear functional $\varphi\in (C_0(K))^*$ there exists a regular complex Borel measure $\mu$ such that
$$
\varphi(f)=\int fd\mu,\ \ \forall f\in C_0(K).
$$
I would like to compute, for a Borel set $E\subset K$, the measure $\mu(E)$, not explicitily, but in terms of $\varphi$. I know that
$$
    \mu(E)=\int \chi_Ed\mu,
$$
but it is not necessarily true that $\chi_E\in C_0(K)$. So I could try to approximate $\chi_E$ by continuous functions $f\in C_0(K)$ such that $Imf\subset[0,1]$.

Define $\mathcal I=\{L: L\subset E\mbox{ and $L$ is compact}\}$. Then $\mathcal I$ is a directed set, if we equip it with the order "$\subset$". Also define $\mathcal J=\{U: E\subset U\mbox{ and $L$ is open}\}$. This is a directed set, if we equip it with the order "$\supset$". Then, the set $\mathcal I\times\mathcal J$ equipped with the order
$$
(L,U)\leq(L',U') \Leftrightarrow L\subset L'\mbox{ or }(L\not\subset L'\mbox{ and }U\supset U'),
$$ 
is a directed set.

For each $(L,U)\in\mathcal I\times\mathcal J$, we have that $L\subset U$ and, using Urysohn's Lemma, I may fix a function $f_{(L,U)}$ such that
$$
   Im f_{(L,U)}\subset[0,1],\ f_{(L,U)}|_{L}\equiv1\ \mbox{ and }\ f_{(L,U)}|_{U^c}\equiv0,
$$
and consider the net $(f_{(L,U)})_{(L,U)\in\mathcal I\times\mathcal J}$.

It is easy to check that $\chi_{L}\leq f_{(L,U)} \leq \chi_U$. Suppose that $\mu$ is positive measure, then it follows that
$$
\mu(L)\leq \int f_{(L,U)}d\mu = \varphi\left(f_{(L,U)}\right) \leq \mu(U),\ \ \forall (L,U)\in\mathcal I\times\mathcal J.
$$
Since $\mu$ is regular,
$$
\mu(E)=\sup\{\mu(L):L\in\mathcal I\} = \inf\{\mu(U):U\in\mathcal J\}.
$$
Then, by doing some boring calculations, we get that
$$
\liminf_{(L,U) \in \mathcal I\times\mathcal J} \varphi\left(f_{(L,U)}\right) \geq \sup\{\mu(L):L\in\mathcal I\} = \mu(E),
$$
and
$$
\limsup_{(L,U) \in \mathcal I\times\mathcal J} \varphi\left(f_{(L,U)}\right) \leq \inf\{\mu(U):U\in\mathcal J\} = \mu(E).
$$
Therefore,
$$
\lim_{(L,U) \in \mathcal I\times\mathcal J} \varphi\left(f_{(L,U)}\right)=\mu(E).
$$
So this is true when $\mu$ is positive. But we may obtain a decomposition $\mu = (\mu_r^+-\mu_r^-)+i(\mu_i^+-\mu_i^-)$, with $\mu_r^\pm$ and $\mu_i^\pm$ positive measures, so this result follows for the general case.

My question is: Is this right?

Comment: I think that your approach works for topological $E$ (open or compact) but not necessarily for Borel sets.

The issue is that when you use the regularity
$$\mu(E)=\sup\{\mu(L):L\in\mathcal I\} = \inf\{\mu(U):U\in\mathcal J\}.$$
the first equality holds for $E$ open, while the second for $E$ compact.

Comment: If I remember right, Borel sets cannot necessarily be approximated from above or below... I would try to use the Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem instead.

Comment: The answer to this question will probably help: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/924783/approximate-a-borel-set-by-a-continuous

Comment: For all open sets $U$ we have $$\mu(U)=\sup\{\mu(K): K \subset U \mbox{compact }\}$$ and for all compact sets $K$ you have $$\mu(K)=\inf\{\mu(U): K \subset U \mbox{open }\}$$ These are sometimes called inner and other  regularity and allow us to connect measurability properties to topological properties...

Comment: According to Wikipedia, every positive Borel measure $\mu$ is said to be regular if: 1) $\mu(K)<\infty$ for every compact $K$; 2) $\mu(E)=\inf\{\mu(U):E\subset U \mbox{ and $U$ is open}\}$, for every Borel set $E$; 3) $\mu(E)=\sup\{\mu(K):K\subset E \mbox{ and $K$ is compact}\}$ whenever $E$ is an open set or $E$ is a Borel set with $\mu(E)<\infty$. The theorem gives us $\mu$ with finite total variation so every Borel set has finite measure and consequently 3) is valid for any Borel set $E$.

Comment: Which wiki page? I'm really not familiar with the extension to Borel sets, but would not be the first thing I don't know ... I found it, that is odd, the resources I use usually only assume inner regularity for open sets.

Comment: @N.S. The results are summarized in sections 7.1-7.3 of Folland's real analysis text.  In particular, corollary 7.6 states that all $\sigma$-finite measures are regular, and every measure induced by an element of $C_0(X)^*$ is finite.

Answer (score -1):

That's the right idea.   You can approximate it as well as you would like as follows: for a given $\varepsilon>0$ use regularity to obtain an open set $U$ and a compact set $K$ with $K\subset E\subset U$ and 
$$\mu(U)-\varepsilon<\mu(E)<\mu(K)+\varepsilon.$$
 (Or apply regularity for positive and negative variations of the real and imaginary parts of $\mu$ if it is complex, and vary the $\varepsilon$ in the above expression accordingly) and use Urysohn to obtain a continuous $f$ with $\chi_{K}\leq f\leq \chi_{U}$, and thus $|\mu(E)-\int f\ d\mu|<\varepsilon$.

I found one small error: in the line 
$$Im f_{(L,U)}\subset[0,1],\ f_{(L,U)}|_{L}\equiv1\ \mbox{ and }\ f_{(L,U)}|_{U}\equiv0,$$
it should be $f_{(L,U)}|_{U^c}\equiv0$.

Comment: Thanks for the report about the error. So, I guess it's too good to be true that the net needs only to converge pointwise to $\chi_E$. Where can I find this kind of result?

Comment: I may have misstated. If the topology on $X$ is reasonably nice then it suffices to consider sequences, hence the dominated convergence theorem would give you convergence. Or perhaps the DCT works for nets.  I'll think about it some more and get back to you.

Comment: @Aweygan DCT fails for nets.